# Prove $\inf_{(a,b)}f = \inf_{[a,b]}f$ for $f(x)$ continuous on $x\in[a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $f(x)$ be continuous for $x \in [a, b]$. Prove that:
>   $$
> \inf_{(a,b)}f = \inf_{[a,b]}f \\
> \sup_{(a,b)}f = \sup_{[a,b]}f
> $$

I need some help with proving the statement above.

I've started with the case for infimum. Since $(a, b)\subset [a, b]$ then:
$$
\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x) \le \inf_{x\in(a,b)}f(x)
$$

By initial conditions $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, hence by Bolzano-Weierstrass there exists $x_0$ such that:
$$
f(x_0) = \inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)
$$

There are three possible scenarios:
$$
x_0 \in (a, b)\\
x_0 = a\\
x_0 = b
$$

Suppose $x_0 \in (a, b)$, then exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x_0
$$

Then:
$$
\inf_{x\in(a,b)}f(x) \le f(x_n)
$$

Upon taking a limit we obtain:
$$
\inf_{x\in(a,b)}f(x) \le \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = f(x_0) = \inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)
$$

So:
$$
\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x) \le \inf_{x\in(a,b)}f(x) \le \inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x) \iff \inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x) = \inf_{x\in(a,b)}f(x)
$$

But there are still two "dangerous" scenarios when the function reaches its infimum at one of the ends of the closed interval. A proof by contradiction might be applicable somehow, yet I'm not sure it's true and how to proceed.

Comment: The first few lines are not quite precise. I think you want to first suppose neither $a$ nor $b$ are minimizers of $f$ over $[a,b]$, then you can indeed conclude a minimizer lies somwhere in $(a,b)$.

Comment: You say "Suppose $f(a)\neq \inf f$. **Then $\inf f$ must be somewhere in $(f(a),f(b))$.**" The bold is incorrect and here is a counter-example: Let $a=-1, b=1$, $f(x)=x^2$. Then $f(a)\neq \inf f=0$ but certainly $\inf f$ is not in between $(f(a),f(b))$ as that is the empty interval $(1,1)$.

Comment: @Michael You are right. Thank you. I've eliminated that part and added some follow-up observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all note that $\inf_{[a,b]}f$ is a lower bound of $f((a,b))$ and hence $\inf_{[a,b]}f\leq\inf_{(a,b)}f$.

Now we want to prove the other direction. We will show that $\inf_{(a,b)}f$ is a lower bound of $f([a,b])$. Obviously for all $x\in (a,b)$ we have $\inf_{(a,b)}f\leq f(x)$. So our only problem can be at the boundary points. Suppose $f(a)<\inf_{(a,b)}f$. Then there is $\epsilon>0$ for which $f(a)+\epsilon<\inf_{(a,b)}f$. But by continuity we know that there is $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in [a,a+\delta)$ we have $f(x)<f(a)+\epsilon$. But that way we get there is a point $x\in (a,b)$ such that $f(x)<\inf_{(a,b)}f$ and this is a contradiction. So $\inf_{(a,b)}f\leq f(a)$ and at the same way we can prove that $\inf_{(a,b)}f\leq f(b)$. Hence $\inf_{(a,b)}f$ is a lower bound of $f([a,b])$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate on the following statement: *But that way we get there is a point $x\in(a,b)$ such that $f(x) < \inf_{(a,b)}f(x)$*? It's not very clear to me

Comment: Disregard my previous comment I figured it out. Thanks once again!

Comment: Take any $x\in (a,a+\delta)$ and you will get $f(x)<f(a)+\epsilon<\inf_{(a,b)}f$.